# Definition of sort Seq

Tags: z3

I would like to know what is the definition of sort Seq. I couldn't find its definition in the Z3 SMT 2.0 Guide. I realized Seq is already defined because I tried to define a sort named Seq. Are there some assertions associated to Seq?

Thanks!!

Maxi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Seq`, `RegEx` (regular expressions) and `FP` (floating point) are "reserved" in Z3 4.0. They were not implemented yet, but they will be available in future releases. For example, Z3 will have builtin functions such as: `seq-last`, `seq-concat`, `seq-length` and many others. In Z3 4.0, these sorts and functions are just "stubs", and behave like uninterpreted sorts and functions. That is why we don't have any documentations for them.